# Replacing an empty space by a string

Tags: java, for-loop, replace

In this class, the objective is to create a method that replaces empty spaces(" ") in a string with the word "like". This is what I got so far; the problem I have is that in the method, if I execute this method on the main file, my program doesn't run the method, how can I solve this?

```
public class Teen 
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int grade;
    private Boolean textMessages;

   public Teen(String theFirstName, String theLastName, int theGrade, Boolean theTextMessages)
    {
        firstName = theFirstName;
        lastName = theLastName;
        grade = theGrade;
        textMessages = theTextMessages;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " is in grade " + grade + " and wants to send this 
        text:";
    }
    
    public String teenTalk(String text)
    {
   for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        String character = text.substring(i, i+1);
        if(character.equals(" "))
        {
            String front = text.substring(0, i);
            String back = text.substring(i+1);
            text = front + " like " + back;
        }
        if(!text.contains(" "))
        {
        text = text;    
        }
    }
        return text;
        
    }
    }



import java.util.Scanner;
public class TeenTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Teen friend = new Teen("John", "Doe", 15, true);
        System.out.println(friend.toString());
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the text message being sent:");
        String like = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println(friend.teenTalk(like));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is sort what I am expecting the console to output. (User input:  I am going to the store; output: I like am like going like to like the like store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will result in an infinite loop if there are spaces to replace, as the replacement string also contains spaces. You should advance the index past the replaced portion upon replacing. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/kj1i77).

```
public static String teenTalk(String text)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        String character = text.substring(i, i+1);
        if(character.equals(" "))
        {
            String front = text.substring(0, i);
            String back = text.substring(i+1);
            text = front + " like " + back;
            i += " like ".length() - 1;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

However, this is extremely inefficient and you would be better off using [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

```
return text.replace(" ", " like ");
```

Comment: It will not work in some cases like 2 space continuously. And congrats for 10K

Answer (score 1):

Replace operation in string when you iterate it would make problem.

Use `replace` method of string

```
String alternative = text.replace(" ", " like ");
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without the 'replaceAll()' method?

Comment: Eklavya - `String#replaceAll` takes a regex as the first argument. You should use `String#replace`.

Comment: @ZackC. you can use StringBuilder to manally to do it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash This will also work though you are right

Comment: @ZackC. and your current approach is very inefficient (using substring everytime)than `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you better use the replaceAll static method from the String class?

```
public String teenTalk(String text) {
     return text.replaceAll(" ", "like");
}
```

If you want to keep your logic using the substring method you also have to reassign the value of your i index since the String you iterate through will be changed.

```
    private String teenTalk(String text) {
        if (!text.contains(" ")) {
            text = text;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            String character = text.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (character.equals(" ")) {
                String front = text.substring(0, i);
                String back = text.substring(i + 1);
                text = front + " like " + back;
                i = i + 5;
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop `for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)` you will will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the line `String character = text.substring(i, i+1);` is executed when the value of `i` is `text.length() - 1` (i.e. last iteration).

Comment: That is incorrect. The second argument to `substring` can be up to **and including** the length of the string. Consult the documentation for details.